# Rspec test puts ( 2d array)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am new to Rspec and I want to create a rspec example for a method which prints a 2d array.

Method which prints the array:

```
 def print_array
    array.each do |row|
      row.each do |cell|
        print cell 
      end
      puts
    end
 end
```

For example, the result from the above code could be:

```
 0 0 0
 0 0 0
 0 0 0
```

So I want to create an expectation(rspec) for the above method.

I tried to check the puts and print (STDOUT) but didn't work:

```
 it "prints the array" do
   ...
   expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with("0 0 0 ...")
   obj.print_array
 end
```

Is there any way to test what exactly is printed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSpec has an [`output` matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher) specifically for this type of thing, so your example will become something like

```
def print_array(array)
  array.each do |row|
    row.each do |cell|
      print cell
    end
    puts
  end
end

RSpec.describe 'print_array' do
  it 'prints the array' do

    expect do
      print_array([
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0],
    ])
    end.to output("000\n000\n000\n").to_stdout
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following link. [output_to_stdout matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher#output-to-stdout-matcher)

we can write like this :

```
expect { puts "1" }.to output("1\n").to_stdout
```

so, your rspec test

```
matrix_format_str = "0 0 0\n0 0 0\n0 0 0\n"
expect { print_array }.to output(matrix_format_str).to_stdout
```